# Prove that a sum of squares to the $n$th power is also a sum of squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $p$ and $q$ be real numbers, let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $i$ be the imaginary unit. Using the factorisation $p^2+q^2=(p+qi)(p-qi)$, prove for any $p$, $q$ and $n$, that the sum of the squares of $p$ and $q$, all raised to the power $n$, $(p^2+q^2)^n$, is also a sum of squares.

I am doing this as a way to practice relating complex numbers to real numbers. I have tried expanding $(p^2+q^2)^n$ using the binomial theorem to no avail. I have also tried rewriting everything in polar coordinates, bringing me nowhere.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(p+iq)^n = a+bi$ for some integers $a$ and $b$. Then

$$
(p^2+q^2)^n = (p+iq)^n (p-iq)^n = (a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2.
$$

Comment: We normally do not answer questions if the OP does not show any effort. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: Why can you assume the jump from $(p+iq)^n (p−iq)^n$ to $(a+bi)(a−bi)$ ?

Comment: Because if $(p+qi)^n=a+bi$ then $(p-qi)^n=a-bi.$ The short reason for this is that complex conjugation is an automorphism. @ArnórBjarkiSvarfdal

Answer (score 0):

Another way,
without using complex numbers,
which is centuries old:

$\begin{array}\\
(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)
&=a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2\\
&=a^2c^2+b^2d^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2\\
&=a^2c^2\mp2abcd+b^2d^2+a^2d^2\pm2abcd+b^2c^2\\
&=(ac\mp bd)^2+(ad\pm bc)^2\\
\end{array}
$

Now iterate.

$(a^2+b^2)^2
=(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2
$

$(a^2+b^2)^3
=((a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2)(a^2+b^2)\\
=((a^2-b^2)a-(2ab)b)^2+((a^2-b^2)b+(2ab)a)^2\\
=(a^3-3ab^2)^2+(3a^2b-b^3)^2
$

Comment: For anybody interested, the shown identity is called the [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity).

Comment: Thanks. I forgot the name.

Comment: Thanks! I had stumbled upon the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity, and can see how it would play out when n is a low number (2, 3, 4...) but can not see the jump to the generalized case for n being any natural number.

Comment: Looks like the terms are alternating parts of $(a+b)^n$. Maybe even real and imaginary parts of $(a+ib)^n$.